# Fetching record from json based on condition

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

I want to fetch data from JSON based on the employeeID. This is how the JSON data looks:

```
{"empDetails":
[
    {
        "employeeId": 1,
        "employeeName": 'Anton DSouz',
        "age": 25,
        "birthday": '05/05/1988',
        "sex": 'Male'
    },
    {
        "employeeId": 2,
        "employeeName": 'John Hussain',
        "age": 26,
        "birthday": '03/25/1987',
        "sex": 'Female'            
    }
]
```

}

This is the code which I am using to fetch the data based on employeeID:

```
Ext.define('EmpDetails',{
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
fields: [
   {name: 'employeeId', type: 'int'},
   {name: 'employeeName', type: 'string'},
   {name: 'age', type: 'int'},
   {name: 'birthday', type: 'date', dateFormat: 'd/m/Y'},
   {name: 'sex', type: 'string', defaultValue: 'Male'}
],
proxy: {
    type: 'rest',
    url: 'data.json',
    format: 'json',
    reader: {
        type: 'json',
        root: 'empDetails'
    }
}
});

Ext.onReady(function(){
EmpDetails.load(1,{
    success: function(empDetails){
        console.log("Age: " + empDetails.get('age'));
    }
});
});
```

But it is not working. The URL it is looking for is incorrect:

```
../../Proxy/data.json/1.json
```

1.json does not exists at all, i is the employeeID present in data.json.

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you're using a rest proxy, it's attempting to append the id to the url so it looks like a normal rest request. You should use an ajax proxy instead.

```
type: 'ajax'
```

Comment: It worked if I change `rest` to `ajax` but am not getting the expected result. If I data is 1, then the age is 25. But again if I send 2, then also the age returned is 25. It should be 26 according to the json data I posted above. Please let me know where is the problem in the above code.

Comment: You're always returning all the records. If you're passing a parameter, you need to apply the appropriate filter in your server code to get the right records.

Comment: @user182944, If this worked, please mark it as solved, it will help others in your situation